# Difference between -lstdc++ and -lstdc++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gnu

Which standards gets invoked by invoking compiler flag "-lstdc++"?
Like  with "-lstdc++11", the c++11 standard gets invoked and the same can be called by "-std=c++11".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-l` flag does not change standards conformance, it is used to specify what libraries to link with.

So, `-lstdc++` would link with a library named `libstdc++.a` or `libstdc++.so`.  On my system, that library can be found at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`, but it will generally be different on your system.

This is no different from specifying something like `-lSDL`, which links with `libSDL.so`, or specifying `-lpng`, which links with `libpng.so`.

If you want to use a certain version of the C++ standard, use the `-std` option (like `-std=c++11`).  This will also link the correct library in, so you do not need to do anything else (such as use any `-l` options).

Comment: But in my case even if i add "-std=c++11" but the library which is getting included is "-lstdc++" and not "-lstdc++11".

Comment: @geek: That's fine, that's just the name of the library.  The compiler is also called `g++`, you don't need to use a different compiler named `g++11`.

Comment: @geek Sure, the library is still called `stdc++` ... you might find its actually a different library on your filesystem though

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the compiler here, but let's assume it is `clang++` or `g++` or something similar.

Then the flag `-l<library>` simply specifies that the library `<library>` should be searched when linking.  This search will include a standard list of search directories and others that may have been added to the library path.

Thus the flag `-lstdc++` simply indicates that library should be searched at link time.  It **has no effect** on the version of c++ that the compiler should think it is compiling.

In contrast, the flag `-std=c++` generally acts as switch to the compiler that:

- indicates the version of c++ in use;
- automatically causes the corresponding library and include paths to be added to the search paths